# Can indefinite article refer to a fact?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Please help me understand.

> Recently she presented me with **a** sweater... ...I was happy to get **a** sweater from her.

In the second sentence can the indefinite article be used to emphasize **the fact** of receiving one?

Am I correct that the second sentence **doesn't necessary mean** that I introduce another sweater?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct.  The sentence (slightly) implies that a sweater (as a class of potential things) was a good choice.

Imagine *Recently she presented me with a sweater. I know how long it takes her to knit large items, so I was happy to get a sweater from her.*

Or: *Recently she presented me with a sweater. I am leaving for a three-week trip to Greenland, so I was happy to get a sweater from her.*

*Recently she presented me with a sweater... ...I was happy to get **the** sweater from her* would have a bit of an implication you were happy to receive ***that** particular sweater,* as opposed to other unspecified possible gifts.  (other sweaters or non-sweater items.)

Contrast:  *Recently she presented me with a sweater.  Given that my sibilngs received knit woolen underwear, I was happy to get **the** sweater from her.*  There is a slight sense that she had three gifts to disburse - someone got the sweater, and two other people got the underwear.

With:  *Recently she presented me with a sweater.  Given that my sibilngs received knit woolen underwear, I was happy to get **a** sweater from her.*  Now, there is a sense that she could have given each person either underwear or a sweater - there was no limit on the number of sweaters disbursed, and the speaker is glad she chose to give him a sweater.

Comment: Adam, thank you. You say "I was happy to get **the** sweater from her would have a bit of an implication you were happy to receive that particular sweater, as opposed to other unspecified possible gifts." <- Can I say then: "I was also happy to be given the socks from her" Would it be contradictory? ; And I thought that saying "I was happy to get **the** sweater from her" means that I talk about that specific sweater, like that particular sweater was a nice gift, but don't compare it with or oppose to any other sweaters or gifts.. Is it also correct?

Comment: Basically, I don't understand if saying: "I was happy to get the sweater from here" can have nothing to do with any comparison or oppositions to other gifts, but just show that I talk about that sweater? Could you clarify it, please?

Comment: Yes. _I was happy to get the sweater from her_ can be used simply to state that you appreciated the gift.

Comment: Adam, this is what I wanted to hear! :) Thank You very much!